# R: Creating bins by a factor when number of observations not divisible by number of bins?

Tags: r

I have a data set in which I have a number of DV's for each level of a factor. The number of DV's/ factor is not consistent. I would like to create quintiles, such that for each level of the factor the smallest 25% of values are assigned to bin 1, the next 25% smallest in bin2, etc,

I have found a package with a NEAR perfect solution: schoRsch, in which the function ntiles creates bins based on levels of the factor, like so:

```r
library(schoRsch)
#{
dv <- c(5, 2, 10, 15, 3, 7, 20, 44, 18)
factor <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
tmpdata <- data.frame(cbind(dv,factor))
tmpdata$factor <- as.factor(tmpdata$factor)
head(tmpdata)


tmpdata$bins <- ntiles(tmpdata, dv = "dv", bins=2, factors = "factor")
tmpdata
#}
```

the output looks like:

```
 dv factor bins
1  5      1    2
2  2      1    1
3 10      2    2
4 15      2    2
5  3      2    1
6  7      2    1
7 20      3    2
8 44      3    2
9 18      3    1
```

My problem occurs when the number of DV's for a particular factor level is not divisible by the number of bins. In the example above, factor 3 has 3 observations, and when sorting into two bins the first bin has one observation, and the second has 2.  However, I would like the priority such that the first bin gets priority for assigning a DV, and the second and so-on.  In my actual data set, for instance, I have a factor with 79 associated DV's and 5 bins. So I would want 16 observations in each of bin 1-4, and then 15 in bin 5.  However this method gives me 16 observation in bins 1 and 3-5, and 15 in bin 2.

Is there any way to specify here my desired order of binning?  Or is there an alternative way that I can solve this problem with another method that allows me to bin on the basis of a factor or, more helpfully, multiple factors?

Thank-you!

Comment: Having trouble understanding. What is a "DV"? Why would breaking into 25% categories yield quintiles? And `ntiles` is presumably from a package that you do not have a `library` call to load.

Comment: Sorry, I don't always know the right lingo. A DV (dependent variable) is my observation. For each level of my factor (aka. every subject in my experiment) there are multiple observations of a DV.  I want to bin these in rank orders so I can find the average value of the DV for the 1/5th smallest--->1/5 largest values for each subject.  I can run ntiles just fine, the package is installed, it just doesn't do precisely what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid you are missing most of my points: 1) EDIT your question to include code to load whatever unnamed package holds `ntiles`. 2) Chopping values into 25% categories gives you _quartiles_, not quintiles. There is a `quantile` function (that will return the cutpoints to do a split) to which you could give a vector depending on whether you want quintiles or quartiles. At this point which one you want is entirely unclear.  And if you don't have values that are evenly partitionable into exactly equal sizes, you give no guidance about what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
foo = function(x, bins) {
    len = length(x)
    n1 = ceiling(len/bins)
    n2 = len - n1 * (bins - 1)
    c(rep(1:(bins - 1), each = n1), rep(bins, n2))
}

table(foo(1:79, 5))

# 1  2  3  4  5 
#16 16 16 16 15

library(dplyr)     
tmpdata %>% group_by(factor) %>% mutate(bin = foo(dv, 2))
## A tibble: 9 x 3
## Groups:   factor [3]
#     dv factor   bin
#  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>
#1     5 1          1
#2     2 1          2
#3    10 2          1
#4    15 2          1
#5     3 2          2
#6     7 2          2
#7    20 3          1
#8    44 3          1
#9    18 3          2
```

Comment: Hi d.b, I am finding your custom function really useful, but unsure how to add an na.rm statement to it. Any suggestions?